# Divide a big dataset in subsets of 100, calculate mean, and plot

Tags: r

I have a huge data set that containts **30000 columns** full with data. I want to take one row and plot the means of sets of **100** *(the first 100 entries, the second 100 entries, and so on)*, so a total of **300** entries. I have the script for the plot ready, but I can't figure out how to divide my data into sets of **100**.

Can anybody of you help? Thank you

Comment: Share code that you have tried.

Comment: The function I want to apply is CV <- function(x, ...){(sd(x, ...)/mean(x, ...))*100}  and I've tried something like byapply(DataSet$column., rep(1:30000, each = 100), rowMeans) but this totally did not work

Answer (score 0):

It may be easier to melt the data, add a column identifier (1:300, repeated 100 times each), and then summarize by that column.

So something like:

```
library(dplyr)
df <- df %>%
   gather(Key, Value) %>%
   mutate(ID = rep(1:300, each = 100)) %>%
   group_by(Key, ID) %>%
   summarize(Mean = mean(Value))

ggplot(df) + 
   geom_point(aes(x = ID, y = Mean))
```

You'll have to customize the code, since I don't have the data structure...